# Windows identity creation using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, rest, iis

I have one WCF REST service which was exposed as the Windows Authenticated  service in the server machine.

As the service is windows authenticated, iam able to form the WindowsIdentity of the requested user  at server side using API      **ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity**.

Problem:

Now i have one client machine which is requesting the windows Authenticated service,
in  client machine the user logged in as clientmachine/testuser.  with the same username and password there is one more user in the Server machine(servermachine/testuser), if the request comes from the client, the  **ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity** is giving the 
windowsidentity of the user in the server machine(servermachine/testuser) instead of clientmachine/testuser, which is wrong, but if the password is different, then the windowsidentity is fine.

Am i doing anything wrong in the service or is this windows behavior?
please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using impersonation, decorate your method with this attribute

```
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Allowed)]
```

Add this to config

```
<behavior name="myServiceBehavior">
    <!-- Other behaviors -->
    <serviceAuthorization impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true" />
</behavior>
```